# How can I pass the entire query results to another page or shell script in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I am working in ASP Classic and need to pass the return values from a query to a shell script.  Currently I can pass single variables to the script, but I need to pass all of the variables.

It may be the same syntax just passing them all to another asp page.
It is way too much code to show here but here is the SQL command:

```
set dbEDIEetsRs = dbEDIEets.execute(SQL_STMT)
```

and from here IK can pass individual variables to other pages like this:

```
response.write "<TD WIDTH='10.00%' BORDERCOLOR=" & vCOLR & "><FONT COLOR=BLUE SIZE=-1><A HREF=details.asp?PID=" & dbEDIEetsRs.fields("PROC_SEQ_NO").Value & ">" & dbEDIEetsRs.fields("TP_NAME").Value & "</A></FONT></TD>"
```

or to a shell script like this:

```
vBaseCommand="c:\progra~1\putty\plink.exe -ssh -l " & vUser & " -pw " & vPwd & " -hostkey " & vHostKey & " " & vHost & " "
vParms="'" & vFileName & "' '" & vISAID & "' '" & vISACtrl & "' '" 
& vGSID & "' '" & vGSCtrl & "' '" & vSTCtrl & "' 2>&1"
vCommand=vBaseCommand & vROOTDIR & "/bin/get_set.sh " & vParms
```

FYI, he above variables were passed this page and requested via:

```
    vFileName = request("FileName")
```

So what I need to do now is pass the entire result to a shell script and/or page.  In the above example of calling a script I need `vParms=dbEDIEetsRs(*)` meaning the whole shebang.

The reason behind this request: the first page a user is asking for a list of data between certain dates. The result of this request is sent to another page listing the data. I now need this list of data to be sent to a shell script where each file will be looked up and zipped up for the user to download.

Thank you

Comment: Check if [GetString Method (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getstring-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) will do.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the spaces were a lot of the problems passing the parameters and so i used the server.encode to pass them to the Bash shell script:

```
vBaseCommand="c:\progra~1\putty\plink.exe -ssh -l " & vUser & " -pw " & vPwd & " -hostkey " & vHostKey & " " & vHost & " "
   
   vSQL_STMT_ENC = Server.UrlEncode(vSQL_STMT)
   vSQL_STMT_IB_ENC = Server.UrlEncode(vSQL_STMT_IB)
   vSQL_STMT_OB_ENC = Server.UrlEncode(vSQL_STMT_OB)
   vORDERBY_ENC = Server.UrlEncode(vORDERBY)
   vEDIDIR_ENC = Server.UrlEncode(vEDIDIR)
   vZIPFILENAME = "BULK_DATA_" & vDateString & ".zip"

   vParms="'" & vSQL_STMT_ENC & "' '" & vSQL_STMT_IB_ENC & "' '" & vSQL_STMT_OB_ENC & "' '" & vORDERBY_ENC & "' '" & vEDIDIR_ENC & "' '" & vZIPFILENAME & "' 2>&1"

   vCommand=vBaseCommand & vScriptDir & "gis_download_data.sh " & vParms
   Set wshShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set wshExec = wshShell.Exec(vCommand)
```

And then in the shell script I used this code to decode the data.  It is working fine so far.

```
function urldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"; }
SQL_STMT_ORIG_DECODED=$(urldecode "$SQL_STMT_ORIG")
SQL_STMT_IB_DECODED=$(urldecode "$SQL_STMT_IB")
SQL_STMT_OB_DECODED=$(urldecode "$SQL_STMT_OB")
ORDERBY_DECODED=$(urldecode "$ORDERBY")
```

Thank you